# If a database has 2 or more pipes, will all of them have the same notification_channel?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Interesting conversation string which may be of value to other Snowflake Users...)

---

***Q:***
I have created two pipes for a database to pump data from ASW s3. The pipes are almost identical with an exception of a target table.

The idea was to insert data into different tables based on original s3 prefix. I created two event notifications on s3 bucket to watch two different prefixes, but since notification_channel generated by snoflake is the same for both pipes, it is impossible to distinguish events on SF side and both pipes inserting data from both s3 folders.

So is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A:***
It is not uncommon for different pipe to have same ARN value in the same region. As long as your target destinations are different in the copy statements, you should be fine injesting data correctly. Pipes in the same regions share the same queue to injest data. It all comes down to configuring the destination properly.

---

***Q:***
My target destinations are different:

create or replace pipe gen3_pipe auto_ingest = true

as

```
copy into gen3_data(device_id, event_datetime, load, origin, inserted_at ) 
from (select $1:device_id, TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ($1:event_datetime), $1:load, metadata$filename, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from @rawdata)
```

create or replace pipe gen2_pipe auto_ingest = true

as

```
copy into gen2_data(device_id, event_datetime, load, origin, inserted_at) 
from (select $1:device_id, TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ($1:event_datetime), $1:load, metadata$filename, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from @rawdata)
```

Both tables gen2 and gen3 are getting the same data, basically gen2 is a copy of gen3.

If both pipes subscribed to the same ARN, how can i distinguish between events?

***A:***
Sharing of the queues(ARN) between pipes is normal. As long as your target table is different in both statements(for both pipes) and does not include purge in any of the pipes, when a file comes int a bucket, it is loaded into both tables gen3_data and gen2_data. You can drop a file and test it out. Let me know if have any problem and we can debug.

---

***Q:***
That is exactly the problem. I want to separate data coming from s3 and for that I have two separate S3 events, hoping snowflake pipes, each can listed to its own event. But both pipes have the same ARN, so separation on this level seems to impossible, or is it?

***A:***
Maybe I am not understanding this correctly. Do you want to load the same file into both target tables or are you differentiating between files that load into their respective tabes? You can include the prefix in the statement when you are creating the external stage. When a data file is uploaded into the bucket, all pipes that match the stage directory path perform a one-time load of the file into their corresponding target tables.

For example: Create two stages
stage for DEV is "`s3://bucket/sub_folder_1`" and for PROD is "`s3://bucket/sub_folder_2`".

Create copy into commands to a target table defined as pointing to respective stages as well.

---

***Q:***
Yes, thank you! I figured the solution with prefixes/folders while creating external stages.

The initial idea was to utilize two events on s3 side with different prefixes, since we need them for other purposes as well.

So there is no way to tell a pipe what queue to listen (ie assign ARN) explicitly, is there?

***A:***
That is correct. The stage reference has to be different for each pipe otherwise they can load same set of files into one or more target tables.